# Can I force AES not to crypt in certain bytes?

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, byte, aes

So I have an AES algorithm that encrypts my array of bytes, so -128 to 127.
Problem is (long story) I don't want AES to transform, after encrypting, any of my bytes to -1 or 127 (because they are both 0 for some reason if I convert into 16bit) and I can't decrypt correctly then. Is there any way to do that?

My application runs something like this:

sound card(16bit) -> array of bytes(8bit) -> AES.encr -> array of encrypted bytes(8bit) -> socket(8bit transmission) -> array of encrypted bytes (16bit) -> array of encrypted bytes(8bit) -> AES.decr -> array of decrypted bytes(8bit)

```
public static int linear2ulaw(int pcm_val){ // 2's complement (16-bit range)              
  int mask;
  int seg;
  //unsigned char uval;
  int uval;

  // Get the sign and the magnitude of the value.
  if (pcm_val<0){
    pcm_val=BIAS-pcm_val;
    mask=0x7F;
  }
  else{
     pcm_val+=BIAS;
     mask=0xFF;
  }
  // Convert the scaled magnitude to segment number.
  seg=search(pcm_val,seg_end);

  // Combine the sign, segment, quantization bits; and complement the code word.

  if (seg>=8) return (0x7F^mask); // out of range, return maximum value.
  else{
     uval=(seg<<4) | ((pcm_val>>(seg+3)) & 0xF);
     return (uval^mask);
  }
  }

static int search(int val,  int[] table){  
  for (int i=0; i<table.length; i++) 
    if (val<=table[i]) return i;
     return table.length;
}

 static final int SIGN_BIT=0x80;    // Sign bit for a A-law byte.
 static final int QUANT_MASK=0xf;   // Quantization field mask.
 static final int NSEGS=8;          // Number of A-law segments.
 static final int SEG_SHIFT=4;      // Left shift for segment number.
 static final int SEG_MASK=0x70;    // Segment field mask.
 public static final int BIAS=0x84;
 static final int[] seg_end={ 0xFF, 0x1FF, 0x3FF, 0x7FF, 0xFFF, 0x1FFF, 0x3FFF, 0x7FFF };

 public static int ulaw2linear(int u_val){
    int t;
    // Complement to obtain normal u-law value.
    u_val=~u_val;
    // Extract and bias the quantization bits. Then shift up by the segment number and subtract out the bias.
    t=((u_val&QUANT_MASK)<<3) + BIAS;
    //t<<=((unsigned)u_val&SEG_MASK)>>SEG_SHIFT;
    t<<=(u_val&SEG_MASK)>>SEG_SHIFT;

    return ((u_val&SIGN_BIT)!=0)? (BIAS-t) : (t-BIAS);
 }
```

Comment: Please post your code that translates the code from 8 to 16bit.  Bottom line: you are not trying to solve the problem the correct way; it would make far more sense to take your data, encrypt it, encode it if you really need to [encode as in base64 encode], send it, un-encode, and then decrypt it

Comment: I don't say you might not be right about the order of encoding and encryption but the problem is conversion. Because either way, at encryption a -1 and/or a 127 will appear and 127 will always be converted to -1, which is bad for decryption. (I edited the first post and put the code)

Comment: First, note that (using 2's complement) -1 is 0x11111111 and 127 is 0x01111111 (i.e. they both have the 7 low bits set to 1 and the only difference is the high/sign bit).  Also, when I call linear_2ulaw(-1) and linear_2ualaw(127), neither returns 0... one returns 127 and one returns 239.  Are you running this on a DSP or something where an int is 16 bits? [Doing a find/replace short for int, I get back 127 / 215 (and an error that prshortf isn't a valid function) or is this not the function that is losing information?

Comment: Well, the information is lost before I can touch it because I send 8 bit over socket (for speed reasons, 16bit is laggy) and I must do ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(lineFormat, ais) at receiver, meaning ais.read(buffer,0,buffer.length) will return buffer in 16bit with conversion problem of -1 and 127 being 0x0 and 0x0.
So I send 8bit buffer example: buffer[1]= -1, buffer[2]=100, buffer[3]=127 and I receive buffer[1]=0, buffer[2]=0, buffer[3]=(-52), buffer[4]=(-2), buffer[5]=0, buffer[6]=0. Reason being I can not make any difference if the first two 0,0 were for -1 or 127.

Comment: But not ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(lineFormat, ais) is the problem, since with the "external conversion" that I posted both linear=ulaw2linear(-1) and linear=ulaw2linear(127) makes linear=0, and it is an int, no DSP.

Answer (score 1):

AES encryption is designed to produce random-looking output, hence those bytes you don't like will always appear in the byte output about every 256 bytes each on average.  You cannot change that, otherwise you would not be using AES.

What you can do is to transform the AES output so the unwanted bytes don't cause any problems.  The usual way to do this is to use [Base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648), as @Foon suggested:

```
AES bytes -> to Base64 -> transmit -> from Base64 -> AES bytes.
```

You can treat the Base64 as a stream of bytes that definitely does not contain either -1 or 128.  All of Base64 is in the printable ASCII range.  You just need to remember to retrieve your original bytes from the Base64 before decrypting.

If Base64 is not a solution, then there are other possibilities, but they are much more complex, and you will have to program then by hand.  With Base64, you can just import library methods.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but AES will generate numbers between -128 and +127 (same as ulaw format) and base64 generate from 0-63. Does it not make even more information loss? Also, I do not think I can do that anyway since at reception ais waits for range -128->127 so, 8bit ulaw, to be able to convert 16bit pcm, aren't things messing up?
It will be something like: capture -> 16bit pcm -> 8bit ulaw(read buffer) -> AES -> base64 ->transmit -> (read buffer)16bit pcm(from base64, which is wrong) -> base64 -> AES -> 16bit pcm -> play

Comment: Base64 takes up more room.  3 bytes of AES output (3 x 8 = 24 bits) map to four 6-bit digits (4 x 6 = 24 bits) in Base64.  There is no information loss provided the conversions are done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I figure it out how to do it.
-1 and 127 were never a problem since encrypting never outputs two 0's in sequence and although it might happen is rare.
The problem was the ulaw encoding (but I don't know why). I switched to alaw and now it works just fine. I have a small background noise(both with and without encryption) but it's acceptable.